# Substituir palavras entre dois arquivos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estou tentando fazer algumas substituiçoes entre dois arquivos: se uma palavra do arquivo 1 estiver na segunda coluna do arquivo 2, substituir essa palavra do arquivo 1 pela palavra da primeira coluna do arquivo 2

**Arquivo 1:**

> comprou tapete grande esperado grande pacote conseqüência surpresa tamanho pequeno queria verificar conteúdo consistente ordem entrega motorista não permitido ainda recomenda ordem
>
> transporte pessoal loja de trabalho passagem completa em todos os lugares lojas sem pessoa ocupa genent circulação visão geral tomar exemplo loja fórum
>
> comprar tempo produto danificado morada tabela tempo queria pedido cópia comprar produto danificado enviar força

**Arquivo 2**:

> comprar,comprou
>
> lugar,lugares
>
> loja,lojas

**Script:**

```
import csv


with open ("arquivo1.txt", "r") as f, open("arquivo2.csv", "r") as f1:
    text = f.read().split('\n')
    text_csv = csv.reader(f1, delimiter = ',')

    for item in text: #percorro a lista de strings
        for novo_item in item.split(): #tento separar cada frase em palavras sem perder a info de que é uma frase

            for elements in text_csv: #percorro a lista do arquivo 2
                lexema = elements[1] # colunas
                lema = elements[0]

                if novo_item == lexema: #se um elemento do meu arquivo 1 esta na segunda coluna do arquivo 2
                    novo_item = novo_item.replace(novo_item, lema) #substituir essa palavra pela primeira coluna do arquivo 2

                print (novo_item)
```

**output esperado:**

> **comprar** tapete grande esperado grande pacote conseqüência surpresa tamanho pequeno queria verificar conteúdo consistente ordem entrega motorista não permitido ainda recomenda ordem
>
> transporte pessoal loja de trabalho passagem completa em todos os **lugar** **loja** sem pessoa ocupa genent circulação visão geral tomar exemplo loja fórum
>
> comprar tempo produto danificado morada tabela tempo queria pedido cópia comprar produto danificado enviar força

Meu output:

> comprou
>
> comprou
>
> comprou
>
> comprou
>
> ...
>
> comprar
>
> comprar
>
> comprar
>
> comprar
>
> ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outro jeito que manteria os "\n" no texto é como o código abaixo, que é até mais simples que o seu.

```
import csv
with open ("arquivo1.txt", "r") as f, open("arquivo2.csv", "r") as f1:
    text = f.read()
    text_csv = csv.reader(f1, delimiter = ',')
    for elements in text_csv:
        novo_text= text.replace(elements[1], elements[0])
        text = novo_text
print novo_text
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que seria algo como

```
# coding=utf-8

import csv
aa = ""

with open ("arquivo1.txt", "r") as f, open("arquivo2.csv", "r") as f1:
    text = f.read().split('\n')
    text_csv = csv.reader(f1, delimiter = ',')
    for item in text: #percorro a lista de strings
        for novo_item in item.split(): #tento separar cada frase em palavras sem perder a info de que é uma frase

            for elements in text_csv: #percorro a lista do arquivo 2
                lexema = elements[1] # colunas
                lema = elements[0]

                if novo_item == lexema: #se um elemento do meu arquivo 1 esta na segunda coluna do arquivo 2
                    novo_item = novo_item.replace(novo_item, lema) #substituir essa palavra pela primeira coluna do arquivo 2
                # print (novo_item)
            aa+=novo_item+' '

print aa
```

Comment: Obrigada, eu entendi mas as minhas três frases se transformam em uma so :(

Comment: Você pode usar um carácter de marcação como um ".", e usar um if para adicioner um ".\n" onde tiver "."

Comment: Obrigada, mas nao posso usar pontuaçao.