# Substituir lista de palavras em um texto

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tenho sempre muita dificuldade com o replace e o sub. Eu sei como funcionam, mas comigo nunca da certo. Eu tenho uma lista de palavras e estou tentando substituir estas palavras em um texto:

**Texto:**

> Brasil, oficialmente República Federativa do Brasil é o maior país da América do Sul e da região da América Latina, sendo o quinto maior do mundo em área territorial (equivalente a 47% do território sul-americano) e sexto em população (com mais de 200 milhões de habitantes). É o único país na América onde se fala majoritariamente a língua portuguesa e o maior país lusófono do planeta, além de ser uma das nações mais multiculturais e etnicamente diversas, em decorrência da forte imigração oriunda de variados locais do mundo. A sua Constituição atual, formulada em 1988, define o Brasil como uma república federativa presidencialista, formada pela união do Distrito Federal, dos 26 estados e dos 5 570 municípios.

**Lista:**

> é
>
> o
>
> da
>
> e
>
> do
>
> em
>
> na
>
> se
>
> de

**Script:**

```
import re
import csv
import itertools

with open('texto.txt', 'r') as file, open('lista.csv', 'r') as stop:
    fichier = file.read().split('\n')
    stopwords = csv.reader(stop)

    for palavras in fichier:
        palavras = palavras.lower()

        for word in stopwords:
            merged_stopwords = list(itertools.chain(*stopwords))
            stopwords_regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, merged_stopwords)))
            replace_stopwords = stopwords_regex.sub('', palavras)

            print(replace_stopwords)
```

O problema é que o meu script começa a fazer replace em vogais dentro das palavras:

**output:**

> brasil, ficialmnt rpública frativa  brasil é  mair país  américa  sul   rgiã  américa lati, n  quint mair  mun m ára trritrial (quivalnt a 47%  trritóri sul-amrican)  xt m ppulaçã (cm mais  200 milhõs  habitants). é  únic país  américa n  fala majritariamnt a língua prtugusa   mair país lusófn  planta, além  r uma s çõs mais multiculturais  tnicamnt divrsas, m crrência  frt imigraçã riun  varias lcais  mun. a sua cnstituiçã atual, frmula m 1988, fin  brasil cm uma rpública frativa prsincialista, frma pla uniã  distrit fral, s 26 stas  s 5 570 municípis.

**EDITADO**

Soluçao encontrada graças à ajuda do Isac e RickADT

**Script:**

```
import re
import csv
import itertools

with open('texto.txt', 'r') as file, open('lista.csv', 'r') as stop:
    fichier = file.read().split('\n')
    stopwords = csv.reader(stop)

    for palavras in fichier:
        palavras = palavras.lower()

        for word in stopwords:
            merged_stopwords = list(itertools.chain(*stopwords))
            # a soluçao esta aqui: para que cada palavra da variavel merged_stopwords seja utilizada, é preciso urilizar o word boundary
            stopwords_regex = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % r'\b|\b'.join(map(re.escape, merged_stopwords)))
            replace_stopwords = stopwords_regex.sub('', palavras)

            print(replace_stopwords)
```

Comment: Mas o objetivo é tirar as preposições para ficar só com as palavras "normais"? Não consegui perceber exatamente o que você quer fazer com este código.

Comment: Exatamente, tirar as preposições e ficar só com as palavras "normais". Mas o script está tirando letras de dentro de palavras normais não sei porque...

Comment: Isso dá para fazer com uma regex no texto inteiro, utilizando *word boundary* com `\bPalavra\b` que fica super simples. Tem [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/ZSKZXo/1) um exemplo simplificado do que estou a tentar dizer

Comment: da uma olhada aqui
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310696/substituir-palavras-entre-dois-arquivos/310812#310812

Comment: Obrigada, mas infelizmente da erro, como foi bem observado aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658187/replace-all-words-from-word-list-with-another-string-in-python

Comment: Como está codificado o `csv`? Cada palavra ta numa linha de forma isolada ? Se sim porque motivo é um `csv` ?

Comment: Obrigada Isac, consegui resolver com a sua sugestao do _word boundary_ e a do  RickADT :)

Comment: Ainda bem. Aproveite e coloque a sua resolução devidamente explicada, que assim acaba por finalizar a sua pergunta, e potencialmente ajudar outras pessoas que possam ter a mesma questão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por uma questão de clareza, e até porque a solução que colocou não era bem como eu tinha sugerido, deixo aqui a minha sugestão.

A sugestão era aplicar uma regex a todo o texto, que substitua apenas palavras inteiras utilizando o `\b` da sintaxe de regexes para *word boundary*. Isso significa que não é preciso iterar nem as palavras do texto, nem as palavras a excluir.

Assumindo que lê o texto e as palavras a remover com:

```
with open('texto.txt', 'r') as file, open('lista.csv', 'r') as stop:
    fichier = file.read()
    csvstop = csv.reader(stop)
    stopwords = list(itertools.chain(*csvstop))
```

O aplicar da regex e restante código seriam apenas mais duas linhas:

```
    regex = re.compile(r'\b' + r'\b|\b'.join(stopwords) + r'\b')
    replacedtext = re.sub(regex, '', fichier, re.IGNORECASE)
```

A regex foi construida utilizando `\bPalavra\b` e com `|` entre cada uma. A *flag* de `re.IGNORECASE` faz com que apanhe quer seja maiúsculas ou minusculas evitando quaisquer tipos de `lower()`. Inspecionando a regex construída para as *stopwords* dadas tem o seguinte:

```
\bé\b|\bo\b|\bda\b|\be\b|\bdo\b|\bem\b|\bna\b|\bse\b|\bde\b
```

Cada uma das palavras estão a ser capturadas em alternativa com o `|` e o `\b` garante que apenas apanha palavras isoladas, e não no meio de outras.

Vale também lembrar que se retirar uma palavra inteira no meio de uma frase pode ficar com dois espaços seguidos. Dependendo do que vai fazer com o texto pode não querer estes espaços. Consegue remove-los facilmente com outra regex:

```
replacedtext= re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', replacedtext)
```

Em que substitui qualquer cadeia de 2 ou mais espaços por 1 espaço.

Comment: cool! (+1). Eventualmente `r'\b(?:' + r'|'.join(sw) + r')\b'`

Comment: @JJoao Isso é realmente uma alternativa interessante e diria mesmo melhor, pois a regex é mais simples e o *non capturing group* provavelmente garante o mesmo nível de eficiência.

Comment: Outra maneira: `"|".join("\\b{0}\\b".format(x) for x in stopwords)` que traz o mesmo output: `\bé\b|\bo\b|\bda\b|\be\b|\bdo\b|\bem\b|\bna\b|\bse\b|\bde\b`. Caso stopwords seja uma lista

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

txt  = open('texto').read()
lista= open('lista').read() 
sw   = re.findall('\w+',lista)
print(re.sub('\w+', lambda x: '' if x[0].lower() in sw else x[0] ,txt))
```

Aqui vai uma variante Python3:

- `re.findall('\w+',lista)` extrai as stopwords.
- `re.sub('\w+', ... , txt)` para cada palavra do texto, substitui-la por
- `lambda x: '' if x[0].lower() in sw else x[0]` ou seja

  - por `''` se ela pertencer às `sw`
  - por ela própria se não pertencer

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o mais simples seja você quebrar cada linha em palavras, com o método `split` e olhar se essa palavra é ou não uma stopword.

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('texto.txt', 'r') as file, open('lista.csv', 'r') as stop:
    lines = file.read().split('\n')
    csvstop = csv.reader(stop)
    stopwords = list(itertools.chain(*csvstop))

    for line in lines:
        palavras = line.lower().split()
        # filtra as palavras q nao sao stopwords
        palavras = [palavra for palavras if palavra not in stopwords]

        print(" ".join(palavras))
```